# Почему nginx не перенаправляет с порта 80 на порт 8081?

Tags: nginx

У меня есть приложение spring boot которое работает на порту 8081
В nginx удален default конфиг
И настроен прокси с 80 порта на порт 8081 вот конфиг

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/mushroomer.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/mushroomer.error.log;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;


events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Но при заходе на 127.0.0.1 открывается страница с приветствием nginx
Почему не работает прокси конфиг?

Comment: Какой код ответа HTTP при запросах через nginx? Можно содержимое файла `/var/log/nginx/mushroomer.error.log` где будут видны ошибки, происходящие во время запроса?

Comment: Status Code: 304 OK логи пустые

Comment: Какой путь у этого конфигурационного файла (может ли он быть обнаружен nginx'ом)? nginx перезапускали после изменения конфигурации (да, глупый вопрос, и всё же)?

Comment: 7-zete-7
/etc/nginx/sites-available и символическая ссылка в /etc/nginx/sites-enabled nginx перезапускал

Comment: Можете прикрепить к вопросу содержимое файла /etc/nginx/nginx.conf или посмотреть есть ли в нём строчка `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` в http? В папке `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` этот файл — единственный?

Comment: 7-zete-7 прикрепил файл nginx.conf есть еще конфиг phpmyadmin

Comment: В файле `/var/log/nginx/error.log` появляются ошибки при выполнении запросов? Попробуйте так же задать `server_name` в `server` вашего файла (пусть даже `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` или внешний IP хоста) и затем делать запросы по указанному имени.

Comment: Спасибо помогло добавил server_name 127.0.0.1 и заработало

Answer (score 1):

```
upstream serve {
  server 127.0.0.1:8081;
  keepalive 15;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/mushroomer.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/mushroomer.error.log;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://serve;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

не хватало server_name 127.0.0.1